# Mouseover issue on triggered animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I recently discovered/forked this fiddle with a triggered on animation on click (http://jsfiddle.net/james_doe/Lqwm98cd/). I used this as a baseline to create a triggered animation of my own for a screen overlay informing the user an item has been copied to the clipboard. Here is my progress on that so far:

http://jsfiddle.net/james_doe/Lqwm98cd/25/

```js
$('.copy-to-clipboard').click(function(){
  $target1 = $('.copy-success');
  $target1.removeClass('copy-animation');
  setTimeout("$target1.addClass('copy-animation');",100);
  $target2 = $('.copy-success span');
  $target2.removeClass('copy-animation-text');
  setTimeout("$target2.addClass('copy-animation-text');",100)
});
```

```css
body{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.copy-success{
  display: table;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 25px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background: #91e35fe6;
  color: #fff;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.copy-success span{
  display: table-cell;
  opacity: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.copy-animation {
    -webkit-animation: success 2s ease;
    -moz-animation: success 2s ease;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
}
.copy-animation-text {
    -webkit-animation: success-text 1.8s ease;
    -moz-animation: success-text 1.8s ease;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.1s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 0.1s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes success {
      0% { opacity: 0; }
     15% { opacity: 1; }
     85% { opacity: 1; }
    100% { opacity: 0; }
}
@-moz-keyframes success {
      0% { opacity: 0; }
     15% { opacity: 1; }
     85% { opacity: 1; }
    100% { opacity: 0; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes success-text {
      0% { transform: translateY(25px); }
     15% { transform: translateY(0); }
     85% { transform: translateY(0); }
    100% { transform: translateY(-25px); }
}
@-moz-keyframes success-text {
      0% { opacity: 0; transform: translateY(25px); }
     15% { opacity: 1; transform: translateY(0); }
     85% { opacity: 1; transform: translateY(0); }
    100% { opacity: 0; transform: translateY(-25px); }
}

.button {
    background-color: #ccc;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
.button:hover {
    background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="copy-success">
  <span>Copied to Clipboard</span>
</div>

<div class="button copy-to-clipboard">
    Click me
</div>
```

The animation is complete and triggers when clicking the button. However, the issue I am having is whenever the mouse is moved in the slightest bit after clicking the button, the animation resets (moving the mouse frantically causes it to flash like a strobe-light, which is actually kind of cool if I were looking to create that effect).

I've tried messing around with z-index, pointer-events, and other aspects of its build, but nothing seems to prevent this bug. Can anybody help prevent this?

Comment: None of what you're describing happens either here or in the fiddle. Tried Chrome and FF (both latest - too lazy to check) on Linux. My guess, by looking at your js code is that both the examples are incomplete.

Comment: I was looking forward to check out the cool strobe-light effect, but unfortunately for me, but good for you. For some reason the animation works fine in my browser. I've used Google Version 67.0.3396 and Firefox 61.0.1 on a Mac.

Comment: For me the animation resets in 3 seconds after I click on the button. It happens even though I do not even move my mouse

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: My apologies! second time using stack, and still getting the hang of including as many details as possible.

I am experiencing the issue in firefox (ESR 52.9.0 64bit if it helps). The project I am working on only works in firefox at the moment, and haven't reached the troubleshooting stage for other browsers.

I just opened my fiddle in chrome, and although the animation reset isn't an issue, the second animation it's meant to trigger for the "copied to clipboard" text isn't showing up.

With that in mind, I suspect that the issue is with the javascript involved in this demo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot replicate your experience within your fiddle.

Having said that, have you tried disabling the pointer events in your CSS prior to the animation?

```
pointer-events: none;
```

Don't forget to turn them back on after:

```
pointer-events: all;
```

Comment: This worked! Sadly, after reviewing some of the previous comments, it looks like I'll need to make some tweaks to the javascript so the text animation gets triggered in other browsers as well. But that's another issue I can tackle on my own, thank you!